# Clockify API: Time Report for Project and aggregate by User

Tags: api, report, clockify

I would like to create a report for one Clockify project (I do know its ID) agregated by users.
The result would be like this:

**Project XY**

User 1: XX (grouped duration)
User 2: YY (grouped duration)
User 3: ZZ (grouped duration)
etc.

Is there any better way than iterating through all users calling this API?

```
/workspaces/{$workspace_id}/user/{$user_id}/time-entries?project={$project_id}&start={$start}&end={$end}
```

This is too slow and the request return only 50 time entries. Our projects have hundreds (some projects even thousends) of entries.

Comment: Curious about this as well Petr, what did you end up using?

Comment: No news :-/ I use the slow way mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://clockify.me/developers-api#tag-Time-entry) if you go down to **Find time entries for user on workspace** you can see that the `page-size` parameter has a default value of 50. So if you change it to 10000 let's say, you can get away with just 1 query per user.

Comment: It works, thank you! This is probably a new parametr. Or it missed it before...

Comment: I've created this simple tool https://github.com/stefanoschrs/clockify the other day which does this aggregation if you want to check out the calls.